# Equations in electrical circuits

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current, math, equation

This might be more of a math question but when solving electrical circuit problems, if f(x-1)= x
What is f(x)?

Comment: Some context would be useful. Can you [edit] to include a sample circuit problem?

Answer (score 1):

Purely considering the maths, write \$u=x-1\$ then \$x = u+1\$,  \$f(u) = u+1\$, replace name of variable \$f(x) = x+1\$.